# Can Termi-Nation Unity's power be used if you don't have a Mechanical Golem in play?

Tags: sentinels-of-the-multiverse

The variant Termi-Nation Unity character card has the following power:

> ***Reconfigure***
>
> **Power:** Shuffle a Mechanical Golem from play into your deck. Move a Mechanical Golem from your trash into play. You may draw a card.

There was debate at our table about the first sentence. We were in agreement that if an Mechanical Golem is in play, you must shuffle it into your deck (since the text was worded as a command). However, we had two conflicting interpretations about what happens when a Mechanical Golem is *not* in play:

1. If you don't have a Mechanical Golem in play, you can't continue to the rest of the text (thus you can't use this power).
2. If you don't have a Mechanical Golem in play, you just ignore that sentence (or think of it as a command that has no effect) and continue on.

Which interpretation is correct?

Comment: To take with a bit of salt but usually if you have no connection to the first sentence in the followings, it's not linked. Termi-nation Unity is kinda hard to unlock on the app but I really think you can move Mechanical Golems  and draw a card even if there's no Mechanical Golem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sentinels of the Multiverse follows a rule of "Do as much as you can."

Unless an effect explicitly depends on a previous effect actually occurring, then any actions that cannot be performed are simply skipped.

I ran a test case in the video game version (which sources its rules interpretations directly from the game designer Christopher Badell), and here are the results, taken from the log file.

Case 1:  Greatest Legacy uses Gung-Ho to let Unity use a power.  She has no Golems in play or in the trash.  Unity still draws a card.

> Legacy uses the power on America's Greatest Legacy.
>   America's Greatest Legacy's Gung-Ho tried to increase Termi-Nation Unity's HP, but they are already at their maximum HP.
>   Unity uses the power on Termi-Nation Unity.
>   Unity draws Turret Bot.
>   Went from Legacy's UsePower phase to DrawCard phase.

Case 2: Unity uses her power with 1 Golem in play and none in the trash.  Unity destroys her Golem and draws a card.

> Went from Unity's PlayCard phase to UsePower phase.
>   Unity uses the power on Termi-Nation Unity.
>   Termi-Nation Unity's Reconfigure destroys Raptor Bot!
>   GameController moved Raptor Bot to Unity's deck.
>   Unity shuffles their Unity's deck.
>   Unity draws Brainstorm.
>   Went from Unity's UsePower phase to DrawCard phase.

Case 3: Gung-Ho Unity uses her power with no golems in play and 1 in the trash.  Unity reanimates a Golem and draws a card.

> Went from Unity's PlayCard phase to UsePower phase.
>   Unity uses the power on Termi-Nation Unity.
>   Termi-Nation Unity's Reconfigure puts Swift Bot into play.
>   Unity draws Flash Forge.
>   Swift Bot increased the action count of DrawCard by 1.
>   Went from Unity's UsePower phase to DrawCard phase. (Count: 2)

### There are conditional powers, but Unity's is not one of them

If the rest of Unity's effect was conditional upon destroying a Golem, it would be worded like Freedom Six Tempest's power Sacrifice:

> **Sacrifice** - Destroy 1 of your cards.  If you do, draw 3 cards.

Comment: “Unless an effect explicitly depends on a previous effect actually occurring, then any actions that cannot be performed are simply skipped.” Do you have a source for this? Or is it just your summary of rulings? I suspect it is correct, but I’m wondering if it is spelled out anywhere.

Comment: @Thunderforge I don't think it's spelled out anywhere.  I'm pretty sure you can find it on the [Greater than Games forums](https://greaterthangames.com/forums/sotm-game-engine) if you dig through the rules questions, although most of those are answered by experienced players and playtesters rather than the game designers themselves (Christopher chimes in on occasion, but usually for more obscure issues than this) and I'm not up to digging though old rules questions at the moment.  You can observe it in the video game, though, and as I said before video game behavior is considered official.

Comment: One brief search for ["Do as much as you can"](https://greaterthangames.com/search/node/%22do%20as%20much%20as%20you%20can%22)

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of the digital game the card reads

> Destroy a mechanical golem, then shuffle it into your deck. Move a mechanical golem from your trash into play. You may draw a card.

When you try to use this power with no golems in play the game will inform you that there are none in play however if you have a discarded golem in your discard pile it will be put into play.

Yes you can use this power to place a golem in play from the trash even if you don't currently have one in play so the second option is what happens.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Was able to test this with a golem in my discard but not one in play and the goelm was put into play and I did draw a card.